# PowerShell get-child item and get-content a few folders deep

Tags: powershell

My script below only works for 1 folder using the "$_" before prior to the location of the file:

```
get-childitem E:\WebSystems\Configs\ | Foreach-Object {get-content E:\WebSystems\Configs\$_\Web.config} | foreach-object {$_ -replace "Web1", "Web2"} | set-content E:\WebSystems\Configs\$_\Web.config}
```

How about two folders deep? ex: E:\WebSystems\Configs\Folder1\Folder2\Web.config

The following script doesn't work.

```
get-childitem E:\WebSystems\Configs\ | Foreach-Object {get-content E:\WebSystems\Configs\$_\$_\Web.config} | foreach-object {$_ -replace "Web1", "Web2"} | set-content E:\WebSystems\Configs\$_\$_\Web.config}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
get-childitem -recurse -include Web.Config | foreach-object { $name = $_.FullName; get-content $name } | foreach-object {$_ -replace "Web1", "Web2" } | set-content $name
```

I implore you to test this on an isolated temporary directory. You might want to try this at first:

```
get-childitem -recurse -include Web.Config | foreach-object { $name = $_.FullName; get-content $name } | foreach-object {$_ -replace "Web1", "Web2" } | set-content "$name.modified"
```

Comment: I get an error that says "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline."

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally had extra braces around the last expression.

Comment: It says "Invalid regular expression pattern", which is referencing after the word replace.

Comment: Chances are you're not replacing "Web1" with "Web2" and have an error in the regular expression you are applying to `-replace`

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's a directory that I'm replacing and the replace function doesn't support long or complex value. Is there additional script that fixes this issue?

Comment: I found this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/01/17/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-replace-characters-in-a-text-file.aspx#pi162665=1

Comment: @Swoogan please use the full cmdlet instead of aliases. It makes reading answers easier for beginners (and pro's) alike.

Comment: -replace "E:\WebSystems\Configs\Web\Images", "\\WEBSRV01\Images"

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes. '\' becomes '\\', '\\' becomes '\\\\', etc...